# Skip login screen on boot of Windows Server on EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

I want to be able to spin up a new machine and immediately VNC into it without having to enter a username or password.

I've made a User-Script that starts a TightVNC server on boot, but when I connect via a VNC client, it shows me the Windows login screen. Is there a way to auto-login as Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

See the answer here [Auto login Windows Server 2012](https://superuser.com/questions/499724/auto-login-windows-server-2012)

1. Run regedit.exe
2. Navigate to

   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\winlogon
3. Set or create the following keys

> (DWORD)  AutoAdminLogon = 1
> (String) DefaultUserName = Your user name
>
> (String) DefaultPassword = Your password